# How to do Role based authentication in WCF using Windows authentication (Active Directory)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

How to do Role based authentication in WCF using Windows authentication (Active Directory)?

I have a requirement where request shall be authenticated using Windows authentication (Active Directory). There shall be 2 roles defined. The roles shall be mapped to the user groups in the Active Directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`PrincipalPermissionAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.principalpermissionattribute.aspx):

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "MySpecialGroup")]
void SomeMethod()
{
   // Some Code
}
```

The role name is the AD group name.

If you need more control you can use [`PrincipalPermission`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.principalpermission.aspx):

```
void SomeMethod()
{
  if(!this.IsOwnedByCurrentUser())
  {
    PrincipalPermission pp = new PrincipalPermission(null, "SomeSpecialGroup");
    pp.Demand();
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it just adding attribute to the method is enough or do i need to do any conditional check?

Comment: Adding `PrincipalPermissionAttribute` is enough. If anyone which is not member of MySpecialGroup calls `SomeMethod` a security exception is thrown.

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588265/understanding-wcf-windows-authentication ?